# Systematic increase in runtime

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, timing

When I run this simple code, which repeats many times the exact same operation (a differential equation), the runtime (given by `Timing`) increases systematically, from roughly 1 second to 5.

I am using Math 9.0.1.0 on a MacBook Air. 
(Edit: the problem is not reproduced when running the same code with Mathematica 7 on a Linux machine.)

Can somebody else reproduce this? Does anybody know why and what can I do to avoid it?

```
Clear[delta];
delta := NDSolve[{y''[n] + y'[n] - y[n] == 0, y[-3] == 1, y'[-3] == 1}, y, {n, -3, 0}];
Do[{time = Timing[Do[delta, {a, 1000}]]; Print[time]}, {i, 10}]
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem in version 7 under Windows.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem using Mathematica 9.0.1.0 on a 2012 MacBook Air with OS X 10.9.3 - my times are 1.8 to 7.2 seconds.

Comment: It's a duplicate.  Nevertheless, please do report the problem to support at wolfram.com.  I can reproduce this in Mathematica 10 on OS X 10.9.4.

Answer (score 4):

Change to

```
delta := Module[{y}, 
  NDSolve[{y''[n] + y'[n] - y[n] == 0, y[-3] == 1, y'[-3] == 1}, y, {n, -3, 0}]]
```

This is a possible bug.